# Create mysql unique key based on three columns and a specific value

Tags: mysql, unique-key

I have a table with a unique index across two columns `user_id` and `country_id`

I have added a new column `deleted_at` so I can delete rows whilst keeping the data.

I would now like to update the unique key so that it is based on `user_id`, `country_id` and where `deleted_at` IS NULL. Is this possible, if so how?

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+
+ id | user_id | country_id | deleted_at |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
+  2 |    3    |      1     |     NULL   |
+  3 |    3    |      1     | 2012-10-16 |
|  4 |    3    |      1     | 2012-10-15 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+
```

Using the above as reference, rows could not be added because of id 2, however if row 2 was not set a new row could be created.

Comment: user_id and country_id is repeated thru table. How will you achieve unique key from their combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your table mytable should do the trick:

```
alter table mytable drop index user_country;
alter table mytable add 
unique index user_country_deleted (user_id, country_id, deleted_at);
```

**Edit:** I was too quick. According to [CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) this works only for BDB storage.